# How to auto fill-in an input text field with checked checkboxes text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of multiple checkboxes that when I check them, their label text needs to go comma separated in an input field. However, I don't want to display these values in the input field as it is also used for search words.

At the moment I am able to grab the checked boxes text using a button to send it to the input field like this:

```
jQuery('#save_value').click(function() {
  var sel = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
   return jQuery(el).parent().text();
  }).get();
  jQuery("#s").val(sel);
});
```

But **A:** I shouldn't have a button but as soon as you check the values (text) should go to the input field with comma separated, **B:** these values are currently displayed in the field while I would like not to display them in order to keep an empty field while still keeping the data.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  NY
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  LA
</label>
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="save"> <= I don't want this
<input id="s" type="text">
<inputtype="submit"> <= The submit should get all the data in the text field, even those data from the checked boxes that I am grabbing but that I don't want to display to the users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use 2 fields, 1 to receive the user input and other to send the combined data of the checkbox and user input to server so

```
<input id="checkIt" name="checkIt" name="s" type="hidden"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="s" placeholder="Search for..."/>
```

then in the form submit handler

```
jQuery('form').submit(function () {
    var sel = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
        return jQuery(el).parent().text().trim();
    }).get();
    var s = $('#s').val().trim();
    jQuery("#checkIt").val(sel.join()+ ',' + s);
});
```

Comment: ok this is great in regards of issue 1, thanks a lot. Now the text is applied live without the extra button. However, as I specified I have an input field which is used for user free text, are you suggesting to add a hidden input field to save the checkbox values?

Comment: @rob.m yes, a separate field for storing the checkbox values, which can be combined later either in the server side or in client side with the user field

Comment: I changed the js and then added <input id="checkIt" name="checkIt" type="hidden"> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="s" id="s"  placeholder="Search for...">

Comment: But I only get a result of the input text field, which means it is not reading the hidden field. I should get checkboxes + input field. A combination of all these values as results

Comment: @rob.m do you have a form submit?

Comment: @rob.m if so you can use a skeleton like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytk8r9zk/1/

Comment: Yes I do, let me try that

Comment: mm no luck, it is not picking up the hidden field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70760/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-rob-m).